# Use PHP to display user inputs

Tags: javascript, php, html

What I'm trying to do is to use PHP to display the user inputs on a separate page, but when I process the form none of the input values display. I'm having to use javascript for input validation and that works fine but the PHP page is not working.
Here is my code:
HTML and Javascript

survey.php:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <title>Survey Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystylepage.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function validate()
    {

        if (document.information.name.value == "" )
        {
            alert("Please provide your name!" );
            document.information.value.focus();
            return false;
        }
        if (document.information.email.value == "")
        {
            alert("Please provide an email!");
            document.information.value.focus();
            return false;
        }
        if (document.information.major.value == false)
            {
                alert("Please enter your major");
                document.information.value.focus();
                return false;
            }
        return true;
    }

    </script>
  </head>

  <div id="bodycolor">

  <body>

  <div id="container">
  <div id="menu">Menu: 

  <a class="menu" href="index.htm">Home</a> | <a class="menu"                                          
   `href="faculty.htm">Faculty</a> | 
   <a class="menu" href="courses.htm">
  Courses</a> | <a class="gradecalculator" href="gradecalculator.htm">Grade      
  Calculator</a> | <a class="survey" href="survey.htm">Survey</a>         

  </div>

  </div>

  <div id="header">

  <h1><center>CSE Center for Health Information Technology</center></h1>

  <br>

  <div id="links">

  <center><a href="https://www.kennesaw.edu/"><img src="KSU Logo.jpg"      
   alt="Logo" style="width:100px;height:100px;" /></a></center>

  <br>

   <center><a href="http://ccse.kennesaw.edu/">College of Computing and   
   Software Engineering</a></center>

  </div>

  </div>

  <h1>Please enter you information below</h1>
  <form name="information" method="POST" action="action.php"    
  onsubmit="return     
   validate();">
    <table width="500" border="0">
    <tr>
    <td width="150" bgcolor="#99CCFF"><strong>Name</strong></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" size="20" maxlength="20" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#99CCFF"><strong>Email</strong></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="email" size="20" maxlength="20" /></td>
  </table>
  <p> Major:
    <input name="major" type="radio" value="Information Technology" />
    Information Technology
    <input name="major" type="radio" value="Software Engineering" />
    Software Engineering
    <input name="major" type="radio" value="Computer Science" />
    Computer Science</p>
  <p>
  <input type="submit" value="Process" />
  </p>
   <p id="msg"></p>
  </form>

 </body>

</html>
```

Here is the PHP page:

action.php

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Survey Information Processing</title>
</head>

<body>

<h1>Form data</h1>
<p>Name: <?php echo $_POST["name"]?></p>

<p>Email: <?php echo $_POST["email"]?</p>

<p>Major: <?php echo $_POST["major"]?</p>


</body>

</html>
```

I'm totally new to PHP, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: In your form you have `method="GET"` - but you use `$_POST["name"]`. Simply change the method to `method="POST"`

Comment: Oh, and you also have a syntax-error here `<?php echo $_POST["email"]?</p>` and the line below `<?php echo $_POST["major"]?</p>` -- both aren't closed properly in PHP: `?>` (missing the last `>`). Had you enabled [`error_reporting(E_ALL);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php), simply checking your logs would've told you this!

Comment: I like your <center> tags

Comment: I changed the method from GET to POST and ti is still not working

Comment: @rls1982 read the second comment, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form method should be POST.

```
 <form name="information" method="POST" action="action.php" onsubmit="return validate();">
```

And add a name to the submit button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Process" name="submit" />
```

Also, you could add this if condition:

```
<?php 
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($_POST);   // Check if you're getting any POST data
  echo "</pre>";
?>

<?php if (isset($_POST['name'])) { ?>

 <h1>Form data</h1>
 <p>Name: <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?> 
 </p>
 <p>Email: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?> 
 </p>
 <p>Major: <?php echo $_POST["major"]; ?> 
 </p>

<?php } ?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Got some syntax errors from copying the code there. ;-)

Comment: Thanks but it's still not displaying my user inputs on the php page

Comment: Try doing print_r of your POST data?

Comment: I appreciate your help but this is still not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe your error reporting is disabled or something. At least it's supposed to print the POST array. Even if we're doing something wrong, it should print an empty array.

Comment: What can I do to get my user inputs to display? Thanks for your help

Comment: You can use this code. Because if you follow this answer, *it works* (you don't need the first few lines in that action.php-part of it, that's just debugging). I know it will work - unless there's some code you aren't showing us..

Comment: Could you edit the code please? I'm totally new to php and everything I'm showing you is all the code that I got

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is your method is get but you're trying to access through post

Change

```
method="GET"
```

to

```
method="POST"
```

On your form.

Comment: @rls1982 Can you elaborate?

Comment: I changed the method to POST in the html document instead of GET and It still is not displaying the user inputs on the php page

Comment: You need to enable error reporting. `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your `actions.php` file.

Comment: Could you pleae elaborate about enabling error reporting?

Comment: @rls1982 At the top of your `actions.php` file, add `<?php ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL); ?>`

Comment: I did and I'm getting a syntax error at the
print_r($_POST);   // Check if you're getting any POST data

My user inputs still aren't displaying though